# OnClick event is not firing in MozillaFirefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a MVC 4 application ,using JavaScript jQuery for validations.
But the JavaScript functions are not getting triggered in Mozilla Firefox.
Can some body explain me what might be the issue here.

I have the following JavaScript function inside script tag of the page.

```
function dateValidation() { debugger; }
```

and my html button is as follows

```
<button name="button" value="Request VM/s" class="btn active" id="AddNewRequest" onclick="dateValidation()">Request VM/s</button>.
```

When I run the portal in IE the JavaScript function is getting triggered but the issue is with only Mozilla

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: can you post the related code for us

Comment: No code, no real world issue, no solutions, simple. Share some code for us to ponder

Comment: I have the following JavaScript function inside script tag of the page.function dateValidation()
        {
            debugger;         
        } and my html button is as follows <button name="button" value="Request VM/s" class="btn active" id="AddNewRequest" onclick="dateValidation()">Request VM/s</button>. when I run the portal in IE the JavaScript function is getting triggered but the issue is with only Mozilla

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: can you share your javascript code?

Comment: Try refreshing without cache "Ctrl + F5" or press "Ctrl + Shift + R" (Windows,Linux)

Answer (score 0):

try with input instead of button

Something like

```
<input type="button" value="Request VM/s" class="btn active" id="AddNewRequest" onclick="dateValidation()" />
```

one more try which i made and is firing in IE,Chrome as well as Firefox

i created a test.html file which has contents as

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function dateValidation() { alert("hi"); }
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <button name="button" value="Request VM/s" class="btn active" id="AddNewRequest" onclick="dateValidation()">Request VM/s</button>
</body></html>
```

It worked out for me in all browsers.

One possible reason why you might not be getting is you might have put the javascript function in the wrong place. some times your javascript might not be identified.

Comment: @Mamatha Giving you weird suggestion, try updating your firefox.

Comment: i have updated a code. i tried creating the same in html and its working in IE,Chrome and Mozilla. problem might be with your javascript not being invoked.

Comment: even for me its working till alert(). But my requiremnet is to validate the dynamic table values which is creating problem again.

Comment: you haven't written that code here. and the requirement you mentioned is different from what you are saying now.

Comment: _"try with input instead of button"_ - Why would that help?

Comment: @nnnnnn i found some internet links. something of which i would like to share with you http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE

Comment: That link doesn't explain why the OP's JS wouldn't work, especially when OP has a problem in Mozilla and your link says that button elements work in Mozilla. In any case, it would be good to have your reasoning directly in your answer rather than at the other end of a link buried in a comment.

Comment: the browser level compatibility may vary for certain tags. i find that button has rich rendering possibilities, some of them might not be fledged to certain browsers. It was the first try i asked to put input instead of button. In the later step i tried with the same button itself as an edit made to my post. one thing which i did was retaining the first post to edit made.@nnnnnn

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button name="button" type="button" value="Request VM/s" class="btn active" id="AddNewRequest" onclick="dateValidation();">Request VM/s</button>.
```

Comment: What's different about that, just the `type="button"`? Can you add an explanation as to why that would help?